# Reinitialize Rails development and test databases from the current working tree state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, database-schema, rails-migrations

When you work with rails, and run say `db:schema:dump` or `db:structure:dump` from Rake it will write out the state of your development DB into the schema files. When we run the tests, `db:test:prepare` also copies the current state of the development database - which makes sense, to a degree, because you are probably working on a feature that needs database tweaks for the current branch.

However, we often need to reset the development database to the state that can be achieved by performing all the migrations in sequence, and then reset the testing database to conform to that - and then write out the schema/structure that can be committed to the source tree for the production branch. Currently, we do this with this monstrosity of a shell command:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop && bundle exec rake db:create && \
bundle exec rake log db:migrate > /tmp/miglog.log && \
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && \
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop && \
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create && bundle exec rake 
db:test:prepare
```

This looks horrible, is absolutely unreadable and also very slow because every invocation here boots the Rails env afresh.

Here's what I was wondering: could we remove some steps from this command? And could we fold these into a handwritten Rake task? I presume that would be difficult because the Rails environment gets configured differently depending on `RAILS_ENV`, but would love to at least remove the Rails env reloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify this to

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset 
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

The reset task runs drop, create, migrate. Running migrations dumps the schema anyway (unless you've changed `dump_schema_after_migration` to false)

The `test:prepare` step as you know, dumps and loads the schema, and also does a purge (depends slightly on database adapter but basically drops and recreates the database). Given that you have already just dumped the schema, you could change this to

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset 
bundle exec rake db:test:load_schema
```

Lastly, the tasks in db:test largely know that they should only run against the test database - regardless of rails env they use the test database when needed, so you could just do

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset db:test:load_schema
```

Lastly, there are some who would also tell you that running migrations from scratch is heresy and that the definitive source of truth is schema.rb (as generated by your production environment)

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset` seems to be the key here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You you need to reset the databases I really advice you to use this:

```
rake db:drop   # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV (use db:drop:all to drop all databases in the config)
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Also you have a rake task to reset the database:

```
rake db:reset
```

as I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15927159/1006863)

As for testing I strongly recommend you to use Factories ([FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl))and use [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner).